# How can I write compelling blog posts?

Tags: style, blog, reviews

I maintain a blog on which I give anime reviews.

Academically my English is really good, but whenever I am writing a blog post, I am not able to express exactly what I want to say and sometimes I feel the loss of words.  It's like some words are getting repeated frecuently, and that to me it feels like a turn-off.

After reading a particular anime review on my blog I want people get compelled to watch that show. There are are blogs that I have read whose words seem like they go right through my head telling what the writer wants to say. I have also felt that whenever I write it's very straightforward. I want to make it beautiful so that when readers read it, they understand my feelings that I have at the time of writing. Sometimes I just want to be a little bit funny or just a little bit sarcastic, and even if I am criticising something it doesn't look rude.

Maybe I just want to know how to write a blog in the best way possible.

Comment: Some recommend reviews/essays as conversational, as if you are speaking directly to 1 person you know well. This was in the context of youtube video essays, but something about your writing makes me think that might work for you, especially as you want to inspire with feelings and impressions. Your vocabulary and flow are excellent. You have charm and communication skill (things you cannot fake), but you will need to do it again and again to grow followers – forgive yourself for not always dazzling 100%. Those moments will come. With practice/experience it will become easier to be in the zone.

Answer (score 3):

There is no best way, at least not a best way for all possible readers. Trying to be excellent for the broadest selection of readers is an impossible task. So don't go down that path.

I do not know anything about anime, but I assume that, like other subjects, there are subsets of the topic. I assume that that audiences can be divided based upon their interests in one or more of these subtopics. Part of the success in writing is picking the audience for which your writing is most appropriate. Pick one of those subsets that you are passionate about. Write for that audience. Think of someone that you know who fits into that audience and write for them. Have a conversation with that person, allowing others to listen in.  Listen to what that person might say back to you regarding what you are saying and how you are saying it. Hone your skills.

In this, I am assuming that you are writing mostly for the pleasure of expressing yourself. In such a case, writing a blog entry for a single, truly interested person has to be counted as a success. Anyone else tagging along for the ride is a bonus. Once you find your groove as a writer, then, and only then, can you safely consider branching out to other subtopics.